# EAGLE hiding pad(s) value(s)

Tags: pcb-design, eaglecad

I want to edit [Eagle's PCB](https://www.autodesk.com/products/eagle/overview) [con-amp 1-794681-8 connector part](https://www.diymodules.org/eagle-show-library?type=std&file=con-amp.lbr#device-1-794681-8) in way its pads will show only numbered in PCB Design Window, which means without its values, as is my current situation:
[image: Connector Pads valus unreadable]
The problem is my net names (pads 3-17) are long strings:

1. 3 - INPUT1_SELECT
2. 5 - INPUT2_SELECT
3. 7 - INPUT3_SELECT
4. 9 - INPUT4_SELECT
5. 11 - INPUT5_SELECT
6. 13 - INPUT6_SELECT
7. 15 - INPUT7_SELECT
8. 17 - INPUT8_SELECT

and the PCB itself gets unreadable in some way. How do I achieve such task (removing values from pads) or are there any workarounds without deletion of pads values?

Comment: Smash the component, then you can remove the text from the board without needing to change anything else. Then you can add text as required.

Comment: What version of Eagle are you running?

Comment: @RogerRowland I've smashed and I cannot select text representing pad names.

Comment: @MrPhooky I am using Eagle 8.2.0.

Comment: @KernelPanic These values aren't ones that will be printed out on assemblies or anything so would it be an issue? Or is it just while you're laying out the PCB that it is problematic for you.